# Different image viewer shows different color (brightness?) of jpg image

Tags: jpeg, brightness, photo-viewer

I'm not sure if I should ask this question here or not. I've some images, that have a problem, as the screenshot below shows:

[image: screenshot of problem encounter]

The softwares are as following (left to right, top to bottom):
[qimgv] [gwenview] [gnome image viewer]
[chromium] [okular] [firefox]

I was expecting to see the result like the top left, and the middle bottom version, but when I uploaded it to browser, It shows me the lighter version. I had never encountered the problem like this.

Link of the raw image is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1plym6I93F93NP74QnUOn6g8Rgj_2dorp/view?usp=sharing

(when I open the image on my android phone, firefox give the darker version, chrome give the lighter version)

Comment: Seems like all these different software’s are managing and displaying the .jpg file differently based on how they read the image & interact with display drivers. I'm aware the Firefox does 'Manage' the colour profile of images it opens I imagine this is common practice among any software that opens and image and must generate a picture from that data. You have a few variables in the chain. Raw Image Data (1 & 0’s) -> JPG Reader -> Image Decoding -> Image Generation -> Display Drivers -> Image on Screen. Any of these steps could be slightly different depending on the software used.

Comment: Photoshop says it has an invalid icc profile.

Comment: I agree, most likely as missing or invalid color profile which some viewers substitute with a better guess than others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are image colors inconsistent in different applications after monitor calibration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106106/why-are-image-colors-inconsistent-in-different-applications-after-monitor-calibr)

Comment: Yes, in the context of "color management", different brightnesses are considered different "colors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image has an ICC profile embedded which doesn't seem to be fully defined.

If you compare the ICC information [of your image](http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=https%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2FXdGYks9daJ-J8_nZClcKrqnhlutKq_HE0oBQ9wudau2f4lgOCz7oNCaEtA_sDlkQvNzKfzPhEHj7vWDF7gEU%3Dw770-h977) with that of [another one](http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FUGvpX.jpg) you see that there are some fields missing. Perhaps that's why different viewers handle the image differently?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171794/1256347) at Stackoverflow explains how you can remove the embedded ICC profile from your image, after which I expect the image to be shown with the same brightness regardless of the software.